# Exception: 401 Unauthorized Error | com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

My Code:
GoogleCredential credential

```
    try {
        // Authorize the request.
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccId)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(certFilePath)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Lists.newArrayList(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE))
                .setServiceAccountUser(emailId)
                .build();
```

credential.refreshToken()

Error Log:

```
Error |
Exception: 401 Unauthorized
Error |
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
Error |
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential$refreshToken.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at viewlift.YouTubePublishService.authorizeCredentials(YouTubePublishService.groovy:82)
Error |
    at viewlift.YouTubePublishService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$48c3206b.invoke(<generated>)
Error |
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
Error |
    at viewlift.YouTubePublishService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e11774.authorizeCredentials(<generated>)
Error |
    at viewlift.YouTubePublishService$authorizeCredentials.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
Error |
    at com.viewlift.ViewLiftUtilsService.createSocialAccount(ViewLiftUtilsService.groovy:128)
Error |
    at com.viewlift.ViewLiftUtilsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53f6d4a5.invoke(<generated>)
Error |
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
```

Steps i followed to create service account:

1. I created a web application in oauth 2.0 in credentials
2. Then i took the client id and with this i created a service account
3. Now i am using this service account and p12 certificate generated from it to authenticate and create object of GoogleCredentials
4. As soon as it goes for refresh token i given me 401 exception.

Any help would be appreciated in this case

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube API does not support Service account authentication.

Work around you will need to switch to Oauth2 and authenticate you code once and save the refresh token for use later.  Refresh tokens can expire however its not that often but you will have to watch it and reauthentcate your code if it does expire.

> The [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) supports the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorizing
>   access to private user data.

and

> The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that
>   ***do not*** access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does **not**
>   support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to
>   a YouTube account

Comment: Currently i am using service account configured by me only for accessing youtube account. I disagree with your answer. Its just that i am not able to configure another account in the same fashion. My earlier account is able to bring me video and do manipulations on that. But this new account is not getting configured properly. And i am using OAUTH 2.0 only. The above procedure as per my knowledge is OAUTH 2.0.

Comment: My quotes are directly from Googles documentation.   "YouTube Data API does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account."   I wish you luck in doing something that is documented as not being supported.

Comment: setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(certFilePath) <-- service account

Comment: Side note:  Are you sure you should be using YouTubePublish?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

Comment: I read the documentation and nothing is written over there how to do it although i am able to achieve it earlier but this time i am failing badly. This is the reason i came to stack overflow. And YouTubePublish is an internal class. Its not related to API classes.

Comment: i did it via providing the authorization through oauthplayground. This feasible and now its working fine as needed.